# Rails assosiation to self

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Contact` table with `company_id`  also it can be a `company`

so i want to have `Contact.first.company` and `Contact.first.employees`

And i create association like this, in my `Contact` model

```
  has_many :employees, :class_name => "Contact", :foreign_key => 'company_id'
  belongs_to :company, :class_name => "Contact"
```

but `Contact.first.employees` return me empty array instead of my record

I have

```
company = Conctact.first # => id=1
employee = Contact.last.company_id # => 1
```

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Why contact model has_many: employees, Company should have employees

Comment: @GouravNaik because contact can be company(is_company:true)

Comment: "return me empty array" - well, *do* you have records which have company_id=1?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes i have

Comment: `Contact.last.contact_id` - this one? It's the wrong field.

Comment: company_id sorry,mistaken

Answer (score 2):

Do one thing

In Contact Model

```
belongs_to :company
has_many :employees, through: :company
```

In Company Model

```
has_many :contacts
has_many :employees
```

Now

```
Contact.first.company
Contact.first.employees
```

Will give an result

Comment: i don't want to create addition model to it

Comment: @xxx You said a `Contact` **can be** a `Company`, so does that mean a `Contact` can be other things too? If so you're probably looking at a scenario for polymorphic associations.

Comment: You have employees record